# Tag discussion: "rendering", "presentation" and "layout"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

### Background

Here are the tags we'll put under the microscope this time:

- [rendering](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendering) (22 questions)
- [presentation](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presentation) (4 questions)
- [layout](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout) (4 questions)

In discussions about tags, my goal is always to reduce ambiguity and streamline tag usage.

The above tags are definitely related—they are all used in questions about Sitecore's presentation components.

The most popular of the three, `rendering`, is ambiguous. Is it about renderings? Or is it about the rendering engine of Sitecore as a whole? Its usage points to the latter, which makes it synonymous with `presentation`.

`layout` is ambiguous as well. Is it about defining site layouts in Sitecore? Then it [should be pluralized](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318110/) as `layouts`. Or is it about laying out web pages in general?

### Proposal

All in all, I don't feel there is enough reason to keep these three tags, as there are no distinct differences between the ways they are used. So I propose to only keep `presentation`, as it is the least ambiguous of the three. Also, it completely covers the presentation subsystem of Sitecore.

`rendering` and `layout` should then be made synonyms of `presentation`.

Comment: I personally feel that grouping everything under "presentation" is the right thing to do. So +1!

Comment: Done: all tags merged into `presentation`; two synonyms created.